# MySQL 5.7: REGEXP version of PostgreSQL REGEXP_REPLACE

Tags: mysql

I have a CASE STATEMENT in PostgreSQL which I need to convert into a MySQL statement.

```
       CASE
        WHEN mobilenumber ~'^09[0-9]'
        THEN regexp_replace(mobilenumber, '0', '+63')
        WHEN mobilenumber ~'^9[0-9]' AND LENGTH(mobilenumber) = 10
        THEN '+63' || mobilenumber
        ELSE mobilenumber
      END
```

I am using MySQL 5.7. When I run the statement below, I am getting syntax error.

```
CASE
   WHEN mobilenumber regexp ~'^09[0-9]'
   THEN REGEXP(mobilenumber, '0', '+63')
END
```

Any advice please?

-------Update---------

```
CASE
   WHEN mobilenumber regexp ~'^09[0-9]'
   THEN REPLACE(mobilenumber, '0', '+63')
END
```

The problem is I am REGEXP in my `THEN` instead of `REPLACE`. I also need to remove the `~` in the `WHEN` statement. When I do that, all `0s` are replaced by `+63`. Is there a way to control this?

Comment: `REGEXP_REPLACE` is available in MariaDB 10.0 and MySQL 8.0.

Answer (score 1):

What about

```
...
WHEN mobilenumber REGEXP '^09[0-9]'
THEN concat('+63', substring(mobilenumber, 2))
...
```

? As far as I understand it, you only want the first zero to be replaced. If the pattern matches, you know that the first digit is a zero. So just simply take the substring after the first character and contact the '+63' in the beginning.